# Find a specific string from a line through all the file

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching, fstream, ofstream

I have a file in which i want to search a specific string in a line then compare that string through the whole file which consists of 5000lines. All lines that match the string will be writen on another text file beneath each other. So far i have succeeded to get that specifi string from the first line and write all those lines that match the specific string. follow is the code that do solve the issue for only the first line.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 //gets the specific string from first line
 string FirstLineSplitedString()
 {
ifstream infile;
infile.open("test.txt");
//prints first line
string fline;
string splited;
if (infile.good())
{
string sLine;
getline(infile, sLine);
fline = sLine;

//string starting from Cap900 till before .waa (specific string)
int first = fline.find('_');
int last = fline.find_last_of('.');
splited = fline.substr (first+1,last-first);

}
return splited;
}


 int main()
 {
string SString = FirstLineSplitedString();
ifstream  stream1("test.txt");
string line ;
ofstream stream2("output.txt");

while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
{
if(line.find(SString) != string::npos)
    stream2 << line << endl;
 }


stream1.close();
stream2.close();
  return 0;
}
```

what i couldnt figure how to do: I dont know how to do this to all the document. i mean when i am done finding the specific string from first line and writing all those lines that match the string, how to go to the next line and do the same steps and write all the lines with matching the string beneath each other. Besides if there was no match only the line itself will be written to file.

for example: lets say i have a file test.txt that contains the following (written in bold)

**aaaaaa _men there here. there. so on 

bbbb _men there here. there. so on 

aaaabbbbbaa _from from. there. so on 

zzzzzzzz _from from. there. so on  

aaabbbbbaaa _men there here. there. so on 

aabbbbaaaa _men there here. there. so on  

nnnnnnn _from from. there. so on**

when i run the code i get the following lines in my output.txt 
**aaaaaa _men there here. there. so on 

bbbb _men there here. there. so on  

aaabbbbbaaa _men there here. there. so on 

aabbbbaaaa _men there here. there. so on**

which is correct because i want split to get specific stringfrom(_)till last(.) . Now i want to this to next line different from the first and get the results. Below is the output.txt that i want to achieve from test.txt

aaaaaa _men there here. there. so on 
bbbb _men there here. there. so on 
aaabbbbbaaa _men there here. there. so on 
aabbbbaaaa _men there here. there. so on

---

aaaabbbbbaa _from from. there. so on 
zzzzzzzz _from from. there. so on 
nnnnnnn _from from. there. so on

---

this pattern should continue till ast line of the file

sorry for writing so long but i wanted to be as clear as possible. any help would appreciated.
Also not to forget that the line that match the specific string may come below each other or may come 2000 lines after.

Comment: You can edit your question to add more info instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: i think i crossed the limit for editing within the range time. so i am doing it now as you reminded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I take it you need to group the input file lines based in some substring keys.

The simplest way would be to populate in-memory line group collections as your read the file and then after processing the entire input flush the groups to the output file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

string findGroupKey(const string &line)
{
    size_t first = line.find('_');
    if (first == string::npos)
        first = 0;
    size_t last = line.find_last_of('.');
    size_t len = (last == string::npos ? string::npos : last - first + 1);
    // The key includes the start and end chars themselves in order to
    // distinguish lines like "x_test." and "xtest"
    return line.substr(first,len);
}

int main()
{
    // *** Var defs
    // Read the input file as stream
    ifstream inStream("test.txt");
    // line by line placing each just read line into inLine
    string inLine;
    // Place each inLine into its one group
    deque<deque<string> *> linesGrouped;
    // according to the grouping key
    deque<string> keys;

    // *** Read the input file and group the lines in memory collections
    while (getline(inStream, inLine)) {
        string groupKey = findGroupKey(inLine);

        // Find the key in our keys-met-so-far collection
        int keyIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0, keyCount = (int)keys.size(); i < keyCount; i++)
            if (keys.at(i) == groupKey) {
                keyIndex = i;
                break;
            };

        if (keyIndex == -1) {
            // If haven't found the key so far, add it to our key index collection
            keys.push_back(groupKey);
            // and add a new group collection
            deque<string> *newGroup = new deque<string>();
            newGroup->push_back(inLine);
            linesGrouped.push_back(newGroup);
        } else {
            // Otherwise just add the line into its respective group
            linesGrouped.at(keyIndex)->push_back(inLine);
        }
    }

    // *** Write the groups into the output file
    ofstream outStream("output.txt");
    for (int i = 0, groupCount = (int)linesGrouped.size(); i < groupCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, lineCount = (int)linesGrouped.at(i)->size(); j < lineCount; j++)
            outStream << linesGrouped.at(i)->at(j) << endl;
        // Add a delimiter line (uncomment if you need one)
        //if (i < groupCount - 1)
        //  outStream << "-------------------" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Egorov  Thanks egorov but just found out that couldn't compile your code in codeblocks. although i included <windows.h>. I would appreciate if you change it so that be compatible with codeblocks that i run and see the result.

Comment: Fixed to make compatible with codeblocks. Managed to compile with gcc 4.4.0 from MinGW. The updated code is in the original answer now. Are you OK with this version of toolchain? Should I try something else, MS VC for example? BTW, there's no need in  <windows.h>

Comment: Thanks so much Egorov i havent tested for the whole document but i looks its working as expected :). i wanted to give you a vote up but havent got that reputation yet when i get i will surely do :)

Comment: @Egorov it compiled for 2 3 times without any error. but now i get an error something like this: **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr**.

Comment: Just to clarify: compilation now succeeds but execution fails with an exception on certain data. I believe now it's better to communicate directly to try and debug the code. After all the problems are sorted out I'll update the answer. Please contact me via e-mail from my profile's about page for further discussion.

Comment: @Barryj Updated the code for group key extraction. It didn't take into account lines ending with "_". This should hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: tanks to all guys, everything is ok now you made my day  :)

Answer (score 0):

I made new changes, I think that works now and it's easiest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    string line,splited;
    int current_line = 0, first = 0, last = 0;
    ifstream  stream1("test.txt");
    ofstream stream2("output.txt");

    //Set when I'm going to save those distinct keys (splited string)
    set<string>insertedKeys;
    vector<string>my_array;

    while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
    {
        first = line.find('_');
        last = line.find_last_of('.');
        splited = line.substr (first+1,last-first);         
        insertedKeys.insert(splited);           
        my_array.insert(my_array.end(), line);
        //cout << line << endl;             
    }


    //Then, for each key in insertedKeys you're going to find and save in output.txt those lines that match against the current key
    std::set<string>::iterator it = insertedKeys.begin();   
    for (it ; it != insertedKeys.end(); ++it){
        string current_key = *it;
        for(int i=0 ; i< my_array.size() ; i++){
            line = my_array[i];
            if( line.find(current_key) != string::npos ){   
                stream2 << line << endl;    
            }
        }
        stream2 << " ----------------------------------------------------------------------- " << endl;     
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sangoi Firstly i appreciate the time and your effort.I checked your code and understood but its not working. Even the base which is if there is only one line that matches the string then only that line should be written to the file it writes the same line 2 times. secondly for more than one line it just do different things. I am trying to find why the code behaves such strange as what you have suggested is quite logical and should work. Please observe and see if there is something that we both have missed. looking to hearing from you. thanks once more.

Comment: Thanks for corrections above. I think it's working now. Basically, the program is going to find every pattern (string between '_' and '.') inside file "test.txt". Then it's going to write in output.txt those line that matches against every pattern. If you don't undesteand something, please let me now.

Comment: Sangoi thanks. As in the above post Egorov and me has solve the problem yesterday i didnt check your last post but am sure if u have check ed it then it must have been working. during these 3 4 days i have learned alot from this site thanks to your all efforts. i will be using more often after this. have a good day.